# Looking for a regular expression including alphanumeric + "&" and ";"

Tags: python, regex, encoding

Here's the problem:

```
split=re.compile('\\W*')
```

This regular expression works fine when dealing with regular words, but there are occasions where I need the expression to include words like `k&amp;auml;ytt&amp;auml;j&aml;auml;`.

What should I add to the regex to include the `&` and `;` characters?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably want to take the problem reverse, i.e. finding all the character without the spaces:

```
[^ \t\n]*
```

Or you want to add the extra characters:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9&;]*
```

In case you want to match HTML entities, you should try something like:

```
(\w+|&\w+;)*
```

Comment: that will match things like abc;&def... He is tring to match HTML entities.

Comment: The last one almost worked, so I worked from there. (\\W+&\\W+;)* did the trick for me.

Answer (score 6):

I would treat the entities as a unit (since they also can contain numerical character codes), resulting in the following regular expression:

```
(\w|&(#(x[0-9a-fA-F]+|[0-9]+)|[a-z]+);)+
```

This matches

- either a word character (including “`_`”), or
- an HTML entity consisting of

  - the character “`&`”,

    - the character “`#`”,

      - the character “`x`” followed by at least one hexadecimal digit, or
      - at least one decimal digit, or
    - at least one letter (= named entity),
  - a semicolon
- at least once.

/EDIT: Thanks to ΤΖΩΤΖΙΟΥ for pointing out an error.

Comment: I think that the |&(x part should be |&(# .

Answer (score 2):

you should make a character class that would include the extra characters.  For example:

```
split=re.compile('[\w&;]+')
```

This should do the trick.  For your information

- `\w` (lower case 'w') matches word characters (alphanumeric)
- `\W` (capital W) is a negated character class (meaning it matches any non-alphanumeric character)
- `*` matches 0 or more times and `+` matches one or more times, so `*` will match anything (even if there are no characters there).

Answer (score -1):

Looks like this RegEx did the trick:

```
split=re.compile('(\\\W+&\\\W+;)*')
```

Thanks for the suggestions. Most of them worked fine on Reggy, but I don't quite understand why they failed with `re.compile`.

Comment: That doesn't do what you want.  Try matching "<title>".  1) use |; and use r' strings.   r'(\W+|&\W+;)*'